# mod_rewrite and double slash issue

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy

I am getting mod_rewrite and double slash issue

can you please help me out.

```
#       ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
RewriteRule             /phoenix/^(.*)  http://phoenixstagingappa.scan-shipping.com:8080/phoenix/$1 [P]
ProxyPass               /phoenix/       balancer://phoenix/
ProxyPassReverse        /phoenix/       http://phoenixstagingappa.scan-shipping.com:8080/phoenix
RedirectMatch           301 ^(.*)        /phoenix/
RedirectMatch           303 ^/phoenix$   /phoenix/
```

Comment: What do you mean by "double slash issue"?